# Vue-Router Data Fetching only once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm currently using Vue Router's `beforeEnter` hooks to retrieve data for one of my routes.

```
{
    path: '/A',
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      loadData();
      next();
    },
}
```

A simple example of the flow would be:

```
Navigate to Route A --> Loading Data
Navigate to Route B
Navigate to Route A --> Loading Data again
```

How can i prevent the second & obsolete API Call? since it's not important that the data is that up-to-date.
I could do: `if (!dataIsAlreadyThere) loadData()`, but this is somehow not nice to have with many routes. Are there any other solutions or ideas out there?

Comment: Can you make this check in something close to `loadData` instead? For example, all the data fetching routines go through the same place that acts as a (or interacts with) Cache Manager.

Comment: yes of course that would be better then, but this is kind of also part of my question. If any solution exists to only make api calls if necessary, which would be kind of similar to your cache manager

Comment: @Berni use eventbus or vuex for state management

Answer (score 2):

The following should work according to some clues from the vue and vue-router documentations:

1. Wrap your router-view inside a keep-alive element
2. Fetch the API inside the mounted hook of your component:

   mounted () {
     this.data = loadData()
   }

In theory, this should only mount the component once and keep its state alive, even when the router is switching components inside the router-view.

Note that this is not the preferred way which vuejs or the vue-router itself suggest. Vue suggest using external state management like [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex).